# Stacked barplot in ggplot2: print labels once instead of twice

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a stacked barplot with ggplot2 in R. The two layers represent experimental scores at two points in time, here called 'Main2' and 'Main4'. The labels you see in the graph (on or next to the bars) are the number of observations I obtained per word. This number is always the same at Main2 and Main4. Therefore, I want to print it only once per word, not twice. How do I do this?

This is the code that generates the plot:

```
ggplot(data_words, aes(x = Word, y = Score * 100, fill = Cognate)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(group = TestingMoment), stat = "identity", position = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = freq), size = 3, position = position_nudge(y=2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  labs(x = "Word\n", y = "\nAverage score at Main2 and Main4") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#56B4E9")) +
  coord_flip()
```

This is part of the dataset so that you can get an impression of the format:

```
             Word     Cognate TestingMoment     Score freq
1     zwemvleugel     Cognate         Main4 0.9900000   10
2     zwemvleugel     Cognate         Main2 0.9900000   10
3            zeis     Cognate         Main4 0.5558333   12
4            zeis     Cognate         Main2 0.4791667   12
5            zaag     Cognate         Main4 0.7572727   11
6            zaag     Cognate         Main2 0.5336364   11
7             wip     Cognate         Main4 1.0000000   12
8             wip     Cognate         Main2 0.9166667   12
9      wafelijzer     Cognate         Main2 0.6985714    7
10     wafelijzer     Cognate         Main4 0.8414286    7
11         waaier Non-cognate         Main2 0.6666667   15
12         waaier Non-cognate         Main4 0.8666667   15
```

Results of `dput`:

```
structure(list(Word = c("zwemvleugel", "zwemvleugel", "zeis", 
"zeis", "zaag", "zaag", "wip", "wip", "wafelijzer", "wafelijzer", 
"waaier", "waaier"), Cognate = c("Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", 
"Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", 
"Cognate", "Non-cognate", "Non-cognate"), TestingMoment = c("Main4", 
"Main2", "Main4", "Main2", "Main4", "Main2", "Main4", "Main2", 
"Main2", "Main4", "Main2", "Main4"), Score = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.5558333, 
0.4791667, 0.7572727, 0.5336364, 1, 0.9166667, 0.6985714, 0.8414286, 
0.6666667, 0.8666667), freq = c(10, 10, 12, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
7, 7, 15, 15)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), .Names = c("Word", "Cognate", "TestingMoment", "Score", 
"freq"))
```

Edit: If someone could point out how to increase the contrast between the two layers, that would be helpful too.

[image: Barplot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I give it a try but can not test it.

```
ggplot(data_words, aes(x = Word, y = Score * 100, fill = Cognate)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(group = TestingMoment), stat = "identity", position = "identity", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(data=subset(data_words, TestingMoment == 'Main4'), 
            aes(label = freq), size = 3, position = position_nudge(y=2)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        text = element_text(size = 15)) +
  labs(x = "Word\n", y = "\nAverage score at Main2 and Main4") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#56B4E9")) +
  coord_flip()
```

So I am not sure if `TestingMoment` is the correct variable to filter, but I guess you get the idea.

You could use `color` within bar to get an outline around the bars and increase the contrast.

Maybe think about `facet_wrap` to get extra facets.

Answer (score 2):

In your call to `geom_bar`, you basically duplicate what goes into `geom_col`---it's a special case of `geom_bar`. It's quicker and gets the same result to just use `geom_col`.

I think you also probably want `position = "dodge"`, rather than `position = "identity"` so your bars are next to each other instead of on top of each other...maybe I'm mistaken on that.

In `geom_text`, I specified that the data should be the same data passed through the `ggplot` object, but filtered for only Main4 observations, as an example. You could do it other ways---filter for Main2, group by Word and take the one with the largest score using `top_n`, etc. There are definitely still some tweaks you could make to the text positioning, but here's a rough cut.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-    structure(list(Word = c("zwemvleugel", "zwemvleugel", "zeis", 
    "zeis", "zaag", "zaag", "wip", "wip", "wafelijzer", "wafelijzer", 
    "waaier", "waaier"), Cognate = c("Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", 
    "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", "Cognate", 
    "Cognate", "Non-cognate", "Non-cognate"), TestingMoment = c("Main4", 
    "Main2", "Main4", "Main2", "Main4", "Main2", "Main4", "Main2", 
    "Main2", "Main4", "Main2", "Main4"), Score = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.5558333, 
    0.4791667, 0.7572727, 0.5336364, 1, 0.9166667, 0.6985714, 0.8414286, 
    0.6666667, 0.8666667), freq = c(10, 10, 12, 12, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
    7, 7, 15, 15)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L), .Names = c("Word", "Cognate", "TestingMoment", "Score", 
    "freq"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Word, y = Score * 100, fill = Cognate, group = TestingMoment)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = freq), size = 3, nudge_y = 4, data = . %>% filter(TestingMoment == "Main4"), vjust = 1) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
                axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
                text = element_text(size = 15)) +
    labs(x = "Word\n", y = "\nAverage score at Main2 and Main4") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#56B4E9")) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for your help and for adding the reproducible example!

Answer (score 1):

Only use the rows you want for your `geom_text` layer.
E.g, using `filter` from `dplyr`:

```
... +
geom_text(aes(label = freq),
          size = 3,
          position = position_nudge(y=2),
          data = filter(data_words, TestingMoment == "Main2")) +
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only want the labels for the highest Score. So just filter those:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Word, Cognate) %>%
  arrange(desc(Score)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm using one of the other solutions proposed here because that doesn't involve deleting any numbers, but I was wondering how I could use your code to have the graph be printed sorted by Score? If I run your code, I can see that the dataframe gets reordered, but the order of the bars in the graph doesn't change.

Comment: You dont have to overwrite your data. Could just use that pipe inside `geom_text`. Anyhow, changed it.

Comment: Try something along `aes(x = reorder(Word, Score)`

Comment: This goes in the right direction, but it seems the graph is now sorted by Score as averaged over Main2 and Main4, which looks a bit silly. Would it be possible to sort by Main4 only?

Comment: Again, use the appropriate `filter` command for `x` in `reorder`

Comment: I tried `x = reorder(Word, -Score, data = filter(data_words, TestingMoment == "Main4"))` but the graph didn't get sorted by the scores at Main4. Was this what you meant? Thanks for helping out!